# When save password is prompted on iOS app, how to detect if the user has selected Not Now?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, keychain

I have implemented Autofill password into my iOS app. When the user logins for the first time, save password alert is prompted. But how can I know, when the user selects not now ?

I want to trigger an alert to let the user know, they can save their username, so the next time they login they just have to enter the password in the password textfield to login.

Comment: You can't know; It is entirely up to the user. However, I would just pre-populate the username field anyway next time.

Comment: @Paulw11: Thanks for the response. Is there a method to invoke this alert later in the app. Currently I am using textcontenttype on my text fields.